# Find $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(\sin{5x} - \sin{3x})}{\sin{x}}$

Tags: limits, functions

How can I find the limit of: 
 $$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{(\sin{5x} - \sin{3x})}{\sin{x}}$$

Answer (score 5):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(\sin{5x} - \sin{3x})}{\sin{x}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{5\sin{5x}}{5x} - \frac{3\sin3x}{3x}}{\frac{\sin x}{x}}$$
then use the fact
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin ax}{ax}=1$$

Comment: How can I know that: $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin ax}{ax}=1$$? I guess it is coming from $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$$, but how exactly?

Comment: use the L'Hospital's Rule for $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin ax}{ax}$ to show that equal to $1$

Comment: EHE, I have a question

Comment: $\sin x$ becomes $\frac{\sin x}{x}$, but then don't you have to also multiply the numerator by $x$. So wouldn't it be ...  $\frac{x \sin x}{x}$, as you have done in the other scenarioes?

Comment: I believe you have made a mistake. $\sin 5x$ becomes $5x \frac{\sin 5x}{5x}$, not $5 \frac{\sin 5x}{5x}$

Comment: @KSplitX I divided the numerator and  denominator by $x$

Answer (score 4):

**hint**: Use $\dfrac{\sin x}{x} \to 1$ as $x \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\sin 5x - \sin 3x = 2\cos 4x \sin x$ it follows that the function under consideration is equal to $2\cos 4x$ when $x \neq 0$ and hence the desired limit is $2$.